# Combobox newly selected item event not functioning correctly C#

Tags: c#, combobox, bindingsource

I have a combobox which is populated by a binding source. I'm trying to get my program to do the following, when the selection is changed it carries out the following command:

```
dataSetInstance.tbl2.Clear();
oleDbDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = label2.Text;
oleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSetInstance.tbl2);
```

As a button the above piece of code works and I get the results I'm after, but using the `comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted` method with the same code it seems I have to select the item in the combo box twice to gain the same results as the code I've used above in a button click.

Many thanks,

Comment: Is this in a windows form or a web form?

Comment: This is Windows Forms question. I don't think there is ComboBox class in System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `SelectionChangeCommited`, try using `SelectedIndexChnaged`.

Have a look at this sample on MSDN:

- [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. I need an even ideally which triggers after a selection has been fully made, these events seem to do it before its fully made as it always seems to be a selection behind

Comment: Actually it's not entirelly true. If you look at the sample in the link above you will see that you can call `SelectedIndex` inside the event to get the value of the selected item.

Comment: In that case try to access SelectedIndex property inside SelectionChangeCommited. Also, could you post the code that you use to call when index is changed?

Comment: I've got a work around. Basically when a selection changes a text box also updates based on the selection, using the TextChanged for that text box method I was able to update as desired, thanks for your help!